# Exercise: views, layouts and buttons to create android GUI

Tags: android, user-interface, view

Ok, so I'm pretty noobish to android but starting to get the hang of it. Before I move on I would like to ask for some general feedback for creating android GUI using API views, lists and layouts. For the sake of exercise I will use GUI as an example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Fmkv.jpg

Let's say I want the buttons (and perhaps the "Something") to be able to interact with whatever is in the RelativeLayout. In general, what is best practice for creating such a GUI and what API elements would you use to achieve it?

[Removed unnecessary questions]

Any comments, both general and specific, as well as examples are highly appreciated!

Edit: I have looked through your guide, @Mark Lapasa, thanks for an introduction of the basics. My suggested xml-file is then like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<ImageView android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/header" android:layout_height="30dp">
</ImageView>

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/leftLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_below="@id/header">

    <Button android:text="Left btn1"
        android:id="@+id/leftBtn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Left btn2"
        android:id="@+id/leftBtn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/leftBtn1"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Left btn3"
        android:id="@+id/leftBtn3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/leftBtn2"/>  

</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rightLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_below="@id/header">

    <Button android:text="Right btn1"
        android:id="@+id/rightBtn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Right btn2"
        android:id="@+id/rightBtn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/rightBtn1"/>

     <Button
        android:text="Right btn3"
        android:id="@+id/rightBtn3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/rightBtn2"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/footer" android:layout_height="20dp" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
</ImageView>

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/gameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/footer"
    android:layout_below="@id/header"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/rightLayout"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/leftLayout">
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This works fine. However, this isn't best practice. I now have a total of four RelativeLayouts to work with. Is there some smooth solution to achieve this without using unnecessary system resources and power like this? Also, how is the best way to set the widths and heights so that they are device independent?

Comment: Lot of questions, may be split into multiple questions will help. I guess most of them you can try and validate by doing simple changes to your program.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have looked a bit more into the details and come up with a solution that seems not to be the best practice. Any comments to this solution are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used some time on this and think the best way to achieve such results is to use [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are new to Relative Layouts. You might want to try my visual tutorial on it cause I had a hard enough time with the docs:

**A Visual Guide to Relative Layouts In Android**

http://knowledge.lapasa.net/?p=334